# Clamps for cutting PVC or other circular objects

Tags: pvc, security, cutting, saw, circular-saw

This is about as simplistic as it gets...

They make wood clamps, C clamps, etc, for securing objects with a flat surface that you are about to cut.  Whether it's a circular saw, sawzall, jigsaw, whatever.

Is there a clamp for securing various circular/cylindrical objects like PVC pipe?  Or maybe a trick when you have wood clamps?  Various diameters...

I would love to be able to clamp a PVC pipe to my wood sawhorses, hands free, so I can focus on cutting it cleanly with a sawzall or circular saw plunge cut.  Does such a thing or a technique exist?

Comment: Cut a v notch in a board, screw board to sawhorse  and use a clamp to secure the pipe in the v notch. Or two boards side by side just wide enough for the pipe.

Comment: What size! Under 1” get a hand cutter or a cheap wooden miter box. Not a lot out there because the cut can be quite crooked and be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an array of things that will clamp a PVC pipe.

The best thing for a bench is probably a vice clamp - probably need to put a thin rag on each side.   They also make circle clamps but you will need one for various sizes.

Probably the most used plumbing tool is a chain vice.   Coupled with some rubber matting or rags you can clamp PVC tight.

[image]

I have cut a lot of PVC in my life and I have never felt the need to clamp it.  You should be using a mitre saw or you should just buy a PVC pipe cutter - I use both ways.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vee blocks are fairly normal in actual critical applications (such as machine shops.)

For clamping pipe to your sawhorses, a tie down strap or strap wrench will be more than adequate. As would a chunk of rope and a wedge. Or some tape, but that's wasteful.

But if you like, cut some wooden Vee blocks and use them to help apply a normal bar clamp to the task of holding down your pipe on top of the sawhorse.

Answer (score 1):

If i already have my electric miter saw set up i just cut it on the miter saw. ( *do not use the miter saw if you are only cutting off pieces less than 3 or 4 inches as they may get jammed or thrown out at dangerous velocity* )

Most of the time i just hold it against my leg and use a hand saw.

I have been known to hold it against a bench or free hand it using a reciprocating saw or an angle grinder, ( *not recommended and **not against my leg*** )

I have also used bar clamps to secure it to a bench or saw horse, its best if the bar clamp is big enough to hook over the pipe, not directly on the pipe.

Someday, maybe, i will by an actual PVC cutting tool. ( *Hopefully before i have "reciprocating saw" indecent* !)

Think outside the  miter box.

[image]

Photo from; FamilyHandyman.com